# How do I get $\int^\infty_{-\infty} ue^{-u^2/2} du = [-e^{-u^2/2}]$

Tags: integration

How do I get:

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} ue^{-u^2/2} du = [-e^{-u^2/2}]^\infty_{-\infty}$$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} e^{f(x)}=f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I should use integration by substitution. Let $y = -u^2/2$

Comment: and so $\dfrac{dy}{du}=-u$